# How to enable local Gpo in azure VMs using powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, group-policy

We are asked to create an automation code to enable a local group policy(Turn off auto - restart for updates during active hours) for VMs in azure

Tried multiple commands but failed it shows no module find we even tried to install gpo module by Install-WindowsFeatures -Name GPMC